# Finding the null sets of a continuous linear functional

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, duality-theorems

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space and $C_0(X)$ be the $\Bbb C$ $*$-algebra of continuous functions that vanish at infinity. If $\omega \in C_b (X) ^*$, then there exists a complex, finite, regular Borel measure $\mu$ such that $\omega (f) = \int _X f \ \Bbb d \mu$.

Let's say that I want use $\omega$ to check whether a certain $E \subseteq X$ is a null set of $\mu$. Unfortunately, I cannot evaluate $\omega (1_E)$ because $1_E$ is not continuous. How should I proceed then?

Comment: Since $\omega$ is given by a measure, you can use convergence theorems.

Comment: @Jason: Could you please be more specific? Do you mean to choose a net $f_i \to 1_E$ of continuous functions and say that $\mu (E) = \lim _i \omega (f_i)$? In this case, who guarantees that the net $( \omega(f_i) )_{i \in I}$ is convergent? If it is, is the limit independent of the net $(f_i)_{i \in I}$?

Comment: If we additionally specify that $f_i$ takes values in $[0,1]$ for each $i$, then this it follows from the bounded convergence theorem.

Comment: Do you know anything about $E $? Is it open or closed?